# Double Static Array Throws Exception

Tags: java, image, static-array

I am working on an game assignment for my class in eclipse. I have been getting an error:

ClassNotFoundException(throwable);

It stops in

```
public static Jewel[][] grid = new Jewel[8][8];
```

While running the debugger it doesnt seem to enter the new Jewel[8][8]

i certanly have the Jewel Class in the same package, and i cant figure out why it cant find the class. I am assuming that it is trying to generate a different class or the static portion of the class is not being generated at compile time. Any additional comments are welcome;

here is the whole class this is located in

```
package game;

import java.awt.Dimension; 
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlayArea extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9165676032115582474L;

    public static Jewel[][] grid = new Jewel[8][8];

    public PlayArea(){

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Common.jewelWidth*Common.rowColLength,Common.jewelWidth*Common.rowColLength));
        this.setLayout(null);

        for(int i = 0; i < Common.rowColLength; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < Common.rowColLength; j++){
                grid[i][j] = new Jewel();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i = 0; i <Common.rowColLength;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < Common.rowColLength; j++){
                grid[i][j].drawJewel(i, j, g2);
            }
        }
        Jewel grid2 = new Jewel();
        grid2.drawJewel(1, 1, g2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace to the exception I guess. When you say the error is `ClassNotFoundException(throwable)`, that's what it says? It doesn't name a class? When you say "it stops in" you mean the exception throws there or the debugger skips over it? (It won't enter anything there, the existing answers are right about that.)

Comment: while running the debugger it pauses there and throws that object/error. i wonder if i have to clean/ rebuild/ tell eclipse to re-look at the files or something because i commented out that line entirely and it gave the same error,

Comment: If cleaning and rebuilding doesn't work, post the stack trace because it might tell us something useful. Cleaning and rebuilding is always a good idea in a circumstance like this.

Comment: I re-wrote the file to exclude the Jewel class after checking the stack trace.  and that seems to have fixed my issue and everything seems to be working swimmingly. i suppose i should have designed the code better from the beginning. Thanks for suggesting to check the Stack Trace. - If you answer with something along those lines i would gladly mark that as answered.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static Jewel[][] grid = new Jewel[8][8];
```

This will not create instances of Jewel class but merely references to it. You have to explicitly iterate over your 2D array and create new Jewel  instances.

```
grid[i][j] = new Jewel();
```

This is where it will go inside the constructor if you have some code in your default constructor.

Answer (score -1):

```
While running the debugger it doesnt seem to enter the new Jewel[8][8].
```

It wont't enter jewel[8][8] because array indices start from 0. i.e; from 0-7 (count=8)